# How to avoid the use of a complicated metaclass with sqlalchemy declarative

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've just noticed that in [a stackoverflow reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700735/sqlalchemy-mixin-vs-metaclass-modification) sqlalchemy's creator Mike Bayer (zzzeek) said that "Custom metaclasses aren't needed with Declarative for simple use cases, and pretty much not at all for hard use cases either. Mixins + custom bases should be able to do pretty much everything."  This raised my hopes that something I've been doing in sqlalchemy using a custom metaclass with `declarative_base` can be done using mixins + custom bases instead.  However, I have not been able to make it work.  I would greatly appreciate any hints!

I have a mixin `ConciseRelationshipMixin` that enables the creation of relationships using a concise syntax.  It is used as follows:

```
class Eggs(ConciseRelationshipMixin, OtherMixin1, OtherMixin2):
    pass

Spam = declarative_base(cls=Eggs)

class Ham(Spam):
    some_column = Column(Integer)
    crispy_bacon = ConciseRelationship(Bacon)
```

This creates an extra column in `Ham.__table__` to hold the FK of the relationship, as well as the relationship itself under the name `Ham.bar`, using project-specific conventions for the name of the extra column and the `primaryjoin`.   I really like this mixin because it makes the definition of `Ham` look very clear and uncluttered.

The reason I have not been able to implement this without using metaclasses is that I am trying to convert the assigment `crispy_bacon = ...` into *two* assigments `column_for_crispy_bacon = Column(...)` and `crispy_bacon = relationship(...)`, I could not see any other way to do that.

I am also open to replies of the form "you should not be doing this kind of thing, because ...".

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078052/custom-metaclass-to-create-hybrid-properties-in-sqlalchemy) covers basically the same ground, and it has an excellent reply by Mike Bayer (zzzeek).